# Proper way to use IPv6 address range

Tags: ipv6

I have the following IPv6 addresses range, with netmask 64 :

`A:B:C:D:E:0000:0000:0000` -> `A:B:C:D:E:0000:0000:FFFF`

I have to assign some of them to virtual machines.

Should I use `A:B:C:D:E:0000:0000:0000` or should I start with `::1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is possible to allocate addresses to virtual machines from the link prefix connecting the physical machine to a router, that is not the approach I would recommend.

Rather I would recommend that you get the hosting provider to route a shorter prefix to your physical machine. The prefix length you need depend on the number of VMs:

- For 1 VM you need a /64
- For 2 - 14 VMs you need a /60
- For 9 - 194 VMs you need a /56
- For 84 - 2702 VMs you need a /52
- For 776 - 37641 VMs you need a /48

Those numbers are assuming the provider only hand out prefixes on nibble boundaries and that you want a /64 per VM. The overlap between the ranges is because I allowed for an HD-ratio anywhere between 80% and 95%.

The reasons I would recommend getting a prefix routed to the physical machine and subdivide that into a link prefix per VM are twofold.

- A link prefix per VM give you better isolation between the VMs.
- The router no longer need to do neighbor discovery for each VM, which reduce memory usage on the router and traffic on the physical link.

If the hosting provider for some reason refuse to route a prefix to your physical machine, then you can instead bridge between virtual and physical interfaces. This has multiple drawbacks:

- Some VM network bridging implementations have problems with packets being transferred between guest and host. This can lead to scenarios where your guests can communicate with the world but not with the host.
- The MAC address you allocate to each VM will be directly visible to the hosting provider's router. In case the hosting provider are filtering traffic based on MAC address, it may cause legitimate traffic from your VMs to be dropped. That can require dirty workarounds.
- It would be possible for the VMs to spoof each other's IP addresses.
- More traffic and memory will be needed for neighbor discovery.
- More CPU cycles will be needed since each VM need to process each ND packet. This can be mitigated if the bridging implementation understands IPv6 anycast and limits which VM will see each packet.

Comment: I don't follow the math. A `/60` gives you 16 `/64` subnets. Why is it only 14 in your answer? You seem to subtract 2 from each real value.

Comment: @RonMaupin You get 16 if you assume an HD-ratio of 100%. But I think there is more or less general agreement that reaching an HD-ratio of 100% is not realistic. I gave numbers assuming an HD-ratio between 80% and 95%. Which HD-ratio do *you* consider to be realistic?

Comment: That ratio doesn't really apply to IPv6 since you can never use the full  capacity of a single subnet. You can effectively use every IPv6 subnet because they are all the same size, and you don't slide the mask around. We have various nibbles of the Network ID set up to mean certain things, but the last bye is for the subnet, giving 256 different subnets. We can use all those subnets. If we assign `00` to a particular site, then we can use subnets `00` to `ff` for the site.

Comment: @RonMaupin The ratio does not apply to the host ID part of the address. But it still applies to the network part of the address, because that is managed hierarchically. And it was made 64 bits large to accommodate for operating with HD-ratio in the 80-90% range.

Comment: Given a fixed portion assigned in the Network ID, we can, and do, use it to 100%, there is no reason not to. If you take all the sites in an average, we don't, but there is no reason when creating VMs (or any other reason) to not use all the available subnets. With IPv4 it was important since you could have different network sizes (given a network block, you subnet it it various ways, necessitating the HD ratio to determine how efficiently you can use the block), but that isn't the case with IPv6.

Comment: @RonMaupin To me that line of thinking sounds like sticking to habits that only existed in the first place due to shortage of IPv4 addresses. There will be some individual cases where you can get to 100%. But that doesn't mean it is a good idea to plan for it. Every time you push the utilization to 100% at some branch of the hierarchy you are creating a situation where it will be difficult for you to make changes when you need them.

Comment: The whole reason for the HD ratio with IPv4 was because a network block could, and would, be variably subnetted. We don't do that with IPv6. You assign it a block of equal sized networks, and use them all or not. If you run out, you assign more blocks of networks. With IPv4, you had to assign block with more hosts than you think you would ever use, leading to wasted addresses. IPv6 builds in the wasted addresses with subnets that are far larger than you could ever use. The ratio become moot for IPv6. This was discussed at an IPv6 conference which I attended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37835/discussion-between-kasperd-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: "And it was made 64 bits large to accommodate for operating with HD-ratio in the 80-90% range" isn't how it happened. The original design of IPv6 allocation was for 80 bits of network addressing and 48 bits of host addressing. After that was shared with the IEEE they pointed out that future ethernet-follow-on protocols which would use a 64 bit EUI rather than a 48bit MAC. Thus the IPv6 network:host split was moved from 80:48 to 64:64. In short, the design of the addressing scheme was determined by the host requirements and not so much the network hierarchy requirements. Source: was there.